# Swift 3: image does not fit to circle border

Tags: swift, image, border, geometry

I need to put a image on a round border in the navigation bar title. The code bellow should put a round border and set a constraint. The problem is the circle is bigger than image as shown on images i uploaded. What can i do? Thanks.

```
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: profileImageResized)
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 100.0).cgColor
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true

        view.addSubview(imageView)

        let verticalSpace = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView,
                                           attribute: .top,
                                           relatedBy: .equal,
                                           toItem: self.topLayoutGuide,
                                           attribute: .bottom,
                                           multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        view.addConstraints([verticalSpace])
```

[image: Image with imageView.clipsToBounds = true]

[image: Image without imageView.clipsToBounds = true]

Comment: Set this imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `imageView`'s contentMode to `.scaleAspectFill`. That way, the image will fill its frame, with also respecting its aspect.

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

Comment: the4kman, thank you for answer. I already tried "imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill" and "imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill" but didn't work.

Comment: @Enzo Could you do `imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green` to check that you don't have transparent part on your image?

Comment: Larme, I did set background color to green. Now the part of the circle that was empty is filled with green color.

Comment: @Enzo This means that the part where the image does not cover the view is actually *transparent*.

Comment: Thank you Larme and the4kman. I manipulated image to remove transparency and it worked.